# Finding next smallest palindrome, infinite loop

Tags: c, arrays, debugging

I am writing a code to find the next smallest palindrome(integer) . I am (must) using array to deal with too large numbers like below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>
#include<string.h>
void check_pal(int a[],int max)
{
    int i,j,ctr,k;
    while(1)
    {
    for(i=0;i<max;i++)
    printf("%d",a[i]);
         ctr=0;
         k=max-1;
    while(a[k]==9)
    {
        a[k--]=0;//add corner case when k==0

    }
    a[k]++;
    for(i=0,j=max;i<max/2;i++,j--)
       {
           printf("%d",i);
        if(a[i]!=a[j])
            {
                ctr=1;
                break;
            }
       }
    if(ctr==0)
    for(i=0;i<max;i++)
    {
         printf("%d",a[i]);
         if(i==max-1)
            return;
    }
    }
}
void int_convert(char * m,int a[] )
{

    int i,max;
    for(i=0;i<strlen(m);i++)
    {
       //  printf("%c",m[i]);
        a[i]=m[i]-'0';
    }

    max=strlen( m);
    printf("%d\n",max);
    check_pal(a,max);

}
void main()
{   int a[200],max;
    char * m=malloc(sizeof(char)*200);
    scanf("%s",m);
    int_convert(m,a);
    getch();
}
```

The output result is an infinite loop .
For e.g. for input 45 the output must be 55 but it is resulting in 0000000 ..
Please tell me where I am wrong .

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, but 1)You forgot to free the `malloc`ed memory 2)Why do you pass `max` as a parameter to `int_convert`? 3) `n` is unused 4)The recommended signature of `main` is `int main(void)`.

Comment: `k=max;
    while(a[k]==9)` -- `a[k]` is accessing invalid memory location *after* the array. Maybe you need `k=max - 1;
    while(a[k]==9)`?

Comment: setting k=max-1 modifies the array  , but still getting infinite loop . checking the logic again

Comment: Suppose you enter `A` for `scanf("%s",m);`. `max` will be `strlen(m)` which is 1. So, in `check_pal`, `k` will be one and you try to access `a[k]` while `a[k-1]` is the last index.

Comment: something wrong with the logic , check it again. while(a[k]==9) why this is required

Comment: Definitely a problem in your  function `void check_pal(int a[],int max)
`

Comment: @Code_reaper can you please elaborate `smallest integer palindrome`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not difficult to recognize palindromes:

```
int is_palindrome(int a[], int max) {
    for (int i = 0; i < max/2; i++) {
        if (a[i] != a[max-i-1]) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

It is not difficult to increment the value:

```
void next_value(int a[], int max) {
    int i = max - 1;
    a[i]++;
    while (i > 0 && a[i] > 9) {
        a[i] = 0;
        a[i-1]++;
        i--;
    }
}
```

It's easy to display the value:

```
void show(int a[], int max) {
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        printf("%d", a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

With this support it's trivial to find the smallest following palindrome:

```
void check_pal(int a[], int max) {
    while (!is_palindrome(a, max)) {
        next_value(a, max);
    }
    show(a, max);
}
```

By the way, I would call the function `find_pal` rather than `check_pal`.